# Rest API for enabling advanced filtering in couchbase XDCR

Tags: couchbase, xdcr

From Documentation, we can see REST API available only for enable XDCR.
Do we have REST for Enable advanced filtering like Filter Expression in XDCR?

Please let me know where can i find REST API for 
Enable advanced filtering like Filter Expression in couchbase XDCR configuration.
Current couchbase version is 6.0.0 EE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look this is explicitly documented, so I'm not 100% sure if it's supported. But  specify `filterExpression` when you are creating a replication with the `/controller/createReplication` endpoint.

So, for example, this worked for me when I ran it from Postman:

> POST
>   http://localhost:8091/controller/createReplication?fromBucket=travel-sample&toCluster=someOtherCluster&toBucket=travsamp&replicationType=continuous&compressionType=Snappy&filterExpression=myFilterExpression

Check out the [Documentation for /controller/createReplication](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.0/rest-api/rest-xdcr-create-replication.html), (and I'm going to see if I can get filterExpression added to it explicitly).

Comment: I just created a pull request for this, you might want to keep an eye on it: https://github.com/couchbase/docs-server/pull/174